# SQL Server demands scalar variable declaration

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL code in my Management Studio to create a stored procedure. When trying to execute the query, I get an error message:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@Id"

But I have already declared `@Id` - what could be the problem?

My code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DecryptMyName]  
     (@Id Int,
      @MyName varbinary(MAX))
AS
GO
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeyxx
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificatexx;
GO
-- Now list the original ID, the encrypted ID 
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, DecryptByKey(MyName)) 
FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE Id=@Id ;

 -- Close the symmetric key
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeyxx;
GO
```

Comment: You can't have `GO` commands in a stored procedure. Also, if you have multiple statements in a stored procedure, you need to start the procedure with `BEGIN` and end it with `END`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GO` is not allowed in a stored procedure body.  I would recommend that you always enclose the body in `BEGIN`/`END` to avoid this problem.

Does this work?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DecryptMyName]  (
    @Id Int ,
    @MyName varbinary(MAX)
) AS
BEGIN
    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeyxx
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificatexx;

    -- Now list the original ID, the encrypted ID 
    SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, DecryptByKey(MyName)) 
    FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE Id=@Id ;

     -- Close the symmetric key
    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeyxx;

END;
```

If not, you will need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: @EmekaC - if this answer resolved your problem, please go ahead and mark it as 'Answered'.

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove 'Go' word in your query then it will works

This way:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DecryptMyName]  
         (@Id Int,
          @MyName varbinary(MAX))
    AS

    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeyxx
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificatexx;

    -- Now list the original ID, the encrypted ID 
    SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, DecryptByKey(MyName)) 
    FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE Id=@Id ;

     -- Close the symmetric key
    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeyxx;
```

For Best Practices always use BEGIN and END statement for your stored procedure
like this:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DecryptMyName]  
         (@Id Int,
          @MyName varbinary(MAX))
    AS
    BEGIN
    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeyxx
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE Certificatexx;

    -- Now list the original ID, the encrypted ID 
    SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, DecryptByKey(MyName)) 
    FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE Id=@Id ;

     -- Close the symmetric key
    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeyxx;
    END
```